# Font awesome 5 pseudo-class not working with my kit

Tags: css, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

**Note: I haven't added my kit number here**

I am using the Font awesome 5.  I got kit script after login in the font awesome poral. My issue is, If I added below code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Place your kit's code here -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/kitnumber.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <i class="fas fa-thumbs-up fa-5x"></i>
  </body>
</html>
```

then I am getting my icon but if I use pseudo-class then I am not getting the icon.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Place your kit's code here -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/kitnumber.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      .f_icon:after{
         content: "\f164";
        font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
        font-weight: 900;
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 30%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="f_icon"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But the above code is working if I add font awesome css without my kit.

Comment: kitnumber is not a file this is an number that is given by font awesome

Comment: Yes, correct. I haven't added here. I just added kitnumber.js

Comment: edited! check it

Comment: Typo:  <i class="fas fa-thumbs-up fa-5x"></i>  You have 'fas fa-thumbs-up' here.  It should be 'fa fa-thumbs-up'.

Comment: @Mugé, I downloaded the example from font awesome and it is     <i class="fas fa-thumbs-up fa-5x"></i>

Comment: Try without the 's', if it works.

Comment: What is this kitnumber.js?  If you can prevent it, use less script and more css.  Just for one little icon, I don't think it is worth it.

Comment: @Mugé, kitnumber.js is my kit script that i haven;t shared It is just a example.

Comment: you need to keep the same font family, don't change it because you will no more use the V5 but the V4. Check the duplicate for the correct answer

Comment: @TemaniAfif, I used font-family: FontAwesome; insted of font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';  is it correct?

Comment: no, `FontAwesome` is the font-family of the previous version, not the one of FA5. You need to keep the same font and consider the duplicate to fix your issue. Your code works fine with the CSS version and you are missing a configuration for the JS one

Comment: @TemaniAfif, If I use css then it's working but If I use my kit then it's not working. So I used FontAwesome

Comment: check the duplicate to understand why it's not working

Comment: @TemaniAfif, I added font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"; and data-search-pseudo-elements to the script but not getting icon. I have a doubt why you use display:none; to the Pseudo class

Comment: you should get it: https://jsfiddle.net/rkfmqbLa/ .. you are either not using the correct unicode or something else

Comment: then you have for sure the PRO version: https://jsfiddle.net/rkfmqbLa/1/

Comment: @TemaniAfif, Yes this time it is displying. You added         font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Pro'; correct?

Comment: yes, it's the Pro version in your case and not the Free

Comment: @TemaniAfif, Please add your answer, I have to accept it. Because this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update (24/03/2020)**: the bug is fixed starting from the version 5.13

---

You need to correct the font family to consider the use of `Font Awesome 5 Pro`

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Place your kit's code here -->
    <script  src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/97446b8f60.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      .f_icon:after{
         content: "\f164";
        font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Pro';
        font-weight: 900;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="f_icon"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This seems to be a known bug not yet fixed (https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/16054) and your code should work fine when the bug get fixed.

---

Worth to note that using `FontAwesome` will also fix your issue because in the settings the V4 is enabled by default

[image]

You will notice that the icon isn't the same:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Place your kit's code here -->
    <script  src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/97446b8f60.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      .f_icon:after{
         content: "\f164";
        font-family: 'FontAwesome';
        font-weight: 900;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="f_icon"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you inspect the code you can see the loaded files:

[image]

Comment: I want to ask one question for security, Do I need to use https://kit.fontawesome.com/97446b8f60.js in my page or change the name of the file? Because anyone can use my script

Comment: @NarenVerma no, this is my kit, you can keep using your own kit ... you can by the way change the ID to anything you want

Comment: @NarenVerma there is no issue if someone is using your script unless you are paying for the PRO features. If it's the free, then there is no problem

Comment: Oh! that's cool!... thanks for the help. Finally, I got the correct information and answer. Upvote from my side.

Comment: @NarenVerma if you are intrested you can check the update. It was indeed a bug and the use of Free is the correct way but we need to consider Pro until it's fixed

Comment: Oh!.. Let me check the bugs.. Thanks for the help again

Comment: Let me know if you found the answer on github.

Comment: @NarenVerma the answer is to use my code until the bug get fixed

Comment: Yes, I am using your answer, in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Kitnumber.js is not an seperate js, you have to add your number code that is given by font awesome like this,first enter your email then code will be sent to your mail.[image]

That is your kit number, 

Then,there is a problem in your css, add

```
content: "\25AE";  /* that is your text. You can also use UTF-8 character codes*/
font-family: FontAwesome;
```

Comment: I think you haven't read my last comment. I know the kit number but I haven't added in this question because I don't want to share my kit number. I am using corrct kit script which is given by font awesome.

Comment: @AhmedsaysReinstateMonica  obviously by accident. Good answer.  I didn't know about the kit number, I learned something new.